# Testing an Artisan command was queued

Tags: laravel, mocking, phpunit, laravel-6, mockery

In a certain observer class, I've got this code

```
//Just for context
public function updated () {
    Artisan::queue('campaign:resume', ['campaignId' => $campaign->id]);
}
```

The purpose is to test that the command is indeed queued when the conditions met.
I've tried several approaches but as far as I can tell, Queue::fake() doesn't affect the queue method and can't seem to find a way to use Bus::fake to assert this queued command.

This is what I've tested and commented is what I've tried. Again, the content of the Observer is simplified as it doesn't matter.

```
public function testSomeClassShouldQueueACommand() {
        //Arrange
        //Queue::fake();
        //$fakeBus = Bus::fake();
        $campaignObserver = new CampaignObserver();
        //$this->app->instance(\Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\PendingDispatch::class, $fakeBus);
        //Act
        $campaignObserver->updated();
        //Assert
        //Bus::assertDispatched('campaign:resume');
        //Queue::assertPushed('campaign:resume');
        //Artisan::shouldReceive('queue')->with('campaign:resume');
    }
```

I've seen posts where some say: Just pass it to a job or an event and use `Queue::fake`/`Event::fake`.
It's contents aren't something that should be in a Job nor an Event. It doesn't make sense to create a class to handle "queue" of a command if the Artisan can handle queues itself.

Any ideas on how to complete this unit test?

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume method you call us `updated` - in question you showed implementation of `update` method but you called `updated` method instead.

Second, I've tested it in Laravel 8 , but should work same in Laravel 6.

I think there is no way to test it using Laravel built-in fakes.

Let's assume, command for `campaign:resume` is in `App\Console\Commands\TestArtisan` class. Then you should be able to test like like so:

```
$mock = Mockery::mock(\App\Console\Commands\TestArtisan::class . '[handle]')->makePartial();
$this->instance(\App\Console\Commands\TestArtisan::class, $mock);

$mock->shouldReceive('handle')->once()->withNoArgs();

$campaignObserver = new CampaignObserver();

$campaignObserver->updated();

$this->assertSame([
    'command' => 'campaign:resume',
    'campaignId' => 'HERE_YOU_SHOULD_PUT_SOME_CAMPAIGN_ID',
    0 => 'campaign:resume',
], $mock->arguments());
```

So you create partial mock of command and make sure `handle` method was executed. Finally you can run some additional assertions, like for example comparing data in `arguments()` or anything else you need.

Comment: I see. Imma gonna try messing around with it later today, thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use `Queue::fake` to test that the command was queued, however the job class that you need to assert for is `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\QueuedCommand`

For instance:

```
Queue::fake();
// Your code to test that calls Artisan::queue
Queue::assertPushed(QueuedCommand:class)
```

If you need to validate that the right command and arguments are queued, it is a little trickier, since the `data` property containing the command and arguments is protected, but it is still possible to examine the property if you use a `ReflectionClass` https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php.

For example:

```
$command_signature = 'my:command';
$command_arguments_array = ['argument_key' => 'argument_value'];
Queue::assertPushed(function (QueuedCommand $job) use ($command_signature, $command_arguments_array) {
     // The 'data' property of the the QueuedCommand job is protected, so we do this to get the value
     $reflectedClass = new \ReflectionClass($job);
     $reflection = $reflectedClass->getProperty('data');
     $reflection->setAccessible(true);
     $command_data = $reflection->getValue($job);
     return $command_data[0] === $command_signature && $command_data[1] === $command_arguments_array;
});
```

Note that the `data` property is an array with the first item being the command string and the second being an array of arguments.

Comment: What if there are multiple commands are queued in a single call?

Comment: @svikramjeet you can add as many assertPushed statements as you need, and write the logic to return true for each of your commands.